# How do you determine worm color for Large Mouth Bass

Tags: fishing, worms

When I was growing up and fishing for Large Mouth Bass with my grandfather we primarily used plastic worms.  Color and style matters a lot, and different worms had significantly different results.  To compound that, the "magic combination" seemed to change over time.

My grandfather always knew exactly which worm we should be using, but I never saw him trying lots of different worms.

How do you determine the color and style of worm to use when fishing for large mouth bass?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I am out fishing what I look for in plastic/hard bait is the water clarity.  In murky water I tend to use brightly colored bait.  If it is clear water with good visibility I try and use bait that is colored as close to real as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use bright  fleck worms in murky water and in clear water use your darker colored worms with crankbaits i tend to use the kevin vandam signature series sexy shad color crankbaits around structures such as boat ramps on overcast skies when jigging  i tend to use chartruese or white roadrunners when jigging for bass and croppy jigging for panfish i tend to use white or black swirl tail roadrunner around structures such as stumps down deep  when you see bass hittin  the water under a tree that usually means they are jumping at bugs fallin off that tree so use any type of floating bug like creature

Answer (score 1):

Dark worms in clear water, light colored worm in murky water.  I fish some very murkey waters where I end up using a worm with a chartruese tail.

Answer (score 1):

I always catch a ton of bass in Florida when the water is murky. I am a stickler for using Zoom watermelon/red trick worms without a weight. I ALWAYS fish along banks and structure, nothing deeper than 4 feet. I ALWAYS hide from the wind and fish the calm water, I do not recommend fishing in heavy wind with the technique listed above.

HAPPY FISHING!